# Greateat common divisor in Z[i]

Tags: euclidean-algorithm, euclidean-domain, ordered-rings

How do i use the euclidean algorithm to compute the greatest common divisor of two elements in Z[i]?

Comment: The same way you use the Euclidean algorithm with regular integers. Subtract multiples of the number with smallest absolute value from the number with largest absolute value. It's _slightly_ more work to find the best multiples at each step (although some pure integer or pure imaginary multiple ought to always work), but otherwise the algorithm is unchanged.

Comment: The same way you do in $\mathbb Z$?

Comment: @Arthur it doesn't seem all that similar to me

Comment: And I don't see the difference. Give us an example that you've struggled with, tell us where you're stuck, and we'll see if we can't un-stick you.

Comment: @Arthur I got 11 + 17i and 1 + 13i and all I know is that the 'greatest' number is the one with the greater norm, but other than that I only know that I have to compute their fraction in Q(i) and where do I go from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, let's find $\gcd(11+17i,1+13i)$. We clearly see that $11+17i$ has the greater norm, so we can start by subtracting from that. What multiple should we subtract? We could figure that out by division (which, admittedly, is some work), but we see geometrically (which is much easier that division, and while not *optimal*, more than good enough) that since $11+17i$ is somewhere below the $45^\circ$ line, and $1+13i$ is close to the imaginary axis, $(1-i)$ shouldn't be too far off:
$$
\gcd(11+17i,1+13i)=\gcd(11+17i-(1-i)(1+13i),1+13i)\\
=\gcd(-3+5i,1+13i)\\=\gcd(5+3i,1+13i)
$$
where I've used that $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(-ia,b)$. This time, $1+13i$ has the largest norm, so we find a multiple of $5+3i$ which is close to it. This time we want to turn $5+3i$ a bit more than $45^\circ$. Also, $1^2+13^2=170=5\cdot34=5\cdot(5^2+3^2)$ means that $1+2i$ is pretty good (since $1+2^2=5$):
$$
\gcd(5+3i,1+13i)=\gcd(5+3i,1+13i-(1+2i)(5+3i))\\
=\gcd(5+3i,2)
$$
Now we can finish directly:
$$
=\gcd(5+3i-(2+2i)\cdot2,2)\\
=\gcd(1-i,2)\\
=\gcd(1-i,2-(1+i)(1-i))\\
=\gcd(1-i,0)=1-i
$$

Comment: Either that, or just calculate the quotient as a complex number and then round to a Gaussian integer (as in the proof that $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is a Euclidean domain): $\frac{11+17i}{1+13i} = \frac{232-126i}{170}$ which rounds to $1-i$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler I like geometry. It's faster and more intuitive, and I'm willing to sacrifice the possibility of not finding the optimal quotient.